# React-Native: Search from List Items in ListView

Tags: javascript, android, listview, search, react-native

The values or the Employee Names are retrieved from `Firebase` database. I need to search the employees by Name, so as to easily access them on the `ListView`. For example, if i type'S' , all the employee names with "S" should be displayed same as the `ListView`, which is touchable.

Help me implement the Search functionality from the List Items in the `ListView`.

```
class EmployeeList extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.employeesFetch();

        this.createDataSource(this.props);
      }

      componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        // nextProps are the next set of props that this component
        // will be rendered with
        // this.props is still the old set of props

        this.createDataSource(nextProps);
      }

      createDataSource({ employees }) {
        const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
          rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
        });

        this.dataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(employees);
      }

      renderRow(employee) {
        return <ListItem employee={employee} />;
      }



      render() {

        return (
         <View>
         <TextInput 
       style={styles.TextInputStyleClass}
       underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
       placeholder="Quick Search"
        />
          <ListView
            enableEmptySections
            dataSource={this.dataSource}
            renderRow={this.renderRow}
          />
        </View>
        );
      }
    }

    const styles = {
      TextInputStyleClass:{

        textAlign: 'center',
        height: 40,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#ddd',
        borderRadius: 3 ,
        backgroundColor : "#FFFFFF"

        }

  };

    const mapStateToProps = state => {
      const employees = _.map(state.employees, (val, uid) => {
        return { ...val, uid };
      });

      return { employees };
    };

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, { employeesFetch })(EmployeeList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these methods.

In your state have these variables

i) Search text (which you are entering)
ii) a boolean value for knowing whether the user is searching or not
iii) an array for storing filtered array

In your textinput onTextChange function, check if the text is empty or not .

If it is empty set the boolean value as false,
else set the boolean true and filter the array based on search string (you can use lodash for this)

In your list view render the dataSource based on the boolean value.

i.e) dataSource={isSearching ? filteredArray : this.dataSource}